I don't understand why Yup is casting this value as an array
I'm fairly new to Formik and Yup. I'm confused on why the selectedJobType is being typed as an array in my conditional for the languages validation. jobType is a string from a select box, so I would expect selectedJobType to be a string as well. Instead it is coming in as any[].
Here is my code:
import { MyMultiSelect, MySelect } from "@components/Fields";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

interface FormValues {
  jobType: string;
  languages?: number[];
}

const initialValues: FormValues = {
  jobType: "",
  languages: [],
};

const validationSchema = Yup.object({
  jobType: Yup.string()
    .oneOf(["designer", "development", "product", "other"], "Invalid Job Type")
    .required("Required"),
  languages: Yup.array()
    .of(Yup.number().required("Language selection is required"))
    .when("$jobType", (selectedJobType, schema) => {
      // Why is selectedJobType an array?
      console.log("handleChange", field, "isArray:", Array.isArray(value), value);

      return selectedJobType[0] === "development"
        ? schema
            .min(1, "At least one language is required for developers")
            .required("Language selection is required for developers")
        : schema.notRequired();
    }),
});

const SignUpForm = () => {
  const handleChange = async (
    field: string,
    value: string | boolean | number | number[]
  ) => {
    // When jobType is selected, it is not an array.
    console.log("handleChange", field, "isArray:", Array.isArray(value), value);
  };

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={initialValues}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
      onSubmit={() => {}}
    >
      {(formik) => (
        <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
          <MySelect
            label="Job Type"
            name="jobType"
            required
            handleDBSubmit={handleChange}
            selectOptions={[
              { value: "designer", label: "Designer" },
              { value: "development", label: "Developer" },
              { value: "product", label: "Product Manager" },
              { value: "other", label: "Other" },
            ]}
          />

          {formik.values.jobType === "development" && (
            <>
              <MyMultiSelect
                label="Known Languages"
                name="languages"
                handleDBSubmit={handleChange}
                required
                selectOptions={[
                  { value: 0, label: "JavaScript" },
                  { value: 1, label: "Java" },
                  { value: 2, label: "C" },
                  { value: 3, label: "C++" },
                ]}
              />
            </>
          )}
        </form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};

The custom components are MUI AutoComplete components that I'm configuring to work with Formik.
Versions:

Formik: 2.4.6
React: 18.3.1
Yup: 1.4.0
Mui: 5.15.21


I mean I use zod for basically the equivalent of yup, so I'm no expert, but I imagine it's this bit right here:
 languages: Yup.array()


Duo to documentation of Yup, the 'when' function gets keys and a builder function. Keys can be a string or an array of strings(if you need more than one keys of schema).So, the function have array of values which their keys were selected, even if you select only one key.
You can use this code to solve your problem:


.when('$JobType', ([selectedJobType], schema) => {
// your code
})



